# Lua https timeout is not working

Tags: https, lua, openwrt, luasocket

I am using following versions of Lua and it's packets on openWRT environment:

- luasocket-2.0.2
- luasec-0.4
- lua-5.1.4

Trying to use timeout for a `https.request` call. Tried using `https.TIMEOUT` where `local https = require("ssl.https")` and it never time outs. I tried giving a very small `timeout` (I know that I won't get answer in that time and internet connection is OK) also I tried when net connection is disconnected once `https.request` is called. Is it a known issue? or shall I try something else for this. I can guess either `send/recieve` is blocking it for infinite time.

-Swapnel

Comment: It would be nice if You'd provide full code sample. Not the `wall of text manner`. Simplier to read and undestand Your problem :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the timeout on `ssl.https` does not work. You have to set it on `socket.http`.

For instance, if your code looks like this:

```
local https = require "ssl.https"
https.TIMEOUT = 0.01
b, c, h = https.request("https://www.google.fr/")
```

change it to this:

```
local http = require "socket.http"
local https = require "ssl.https"
http.TIMEOUT = 0.01
b, c, h = https.request("https://www.google.fr/")
```