# How to set a timeout for Luasoap using https

Tags: https, lua, timeout, luasec

Im developing an sdk to connect to a soap server. (Under https)

Im using LuaSoap to do it and its working as espected with the xml request but now i need to be able to configure the timeout (im in online payments industry and its really important) but I dont know how to do it in LuaSoap.

To be able to enable the https requests i followed the instructions of LuaSoap documentation using this code

```
local soap = require"soap.client"
soap.https = require"ssl.https"
```

from this point i dont know what to do or where to set the timeout.

Tnx for ur help.

PD.

LuaSoap uses LuaSec to send the request.

Comment: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193454/lua-https-timeout-is-not-working')

Comment: Tnx. i didnt see that answer.